# Is there an alternative to makecab.exe?

Tags: archiving, unicode, cab

I'm trying to create a cab file with files that have **å**, **ä** and/or **ö** in the file name. Makecab doesn't support Swedish characters, apparently, and fails. Is there any program that can make cab files that does support Swedish characters?

Answer (score 0):

## lcab

With Linux or maybe with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) you can use **lcab**. Make sure you backup your files before proceeding. I had no problems with this software but I tested it quickly.

If you click on the archive to view its contents, accented characters may not be displayed correctly. However, you can get a list of correctly accented files and extract them as needed.

```
# Install lcab
sudo apt install lcab
```

[lcab manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/lcab.1.html)

-r ; loop recursively through directories

```
lcab -r * Swedish.cab

lcab v1.0b12 (2003) by Rien (rien@geekshop.be)
nopath          : no
recursive       : yes
quiet           : no
inputfiles      : affärskvinna.odt aftonmåltid.pdf folder/adjö.txt 
outputfile      : Swedish.cab
cabfile         : 374862 bytes (approx. 366.08 Kbytes)
cfileInit: affärskvinna.odt localtime:
cfileInit: aftonmåltid.pdf localtime:
cfileInit: folder\adjö.txt localtime:
tmp,header,folder,...
done
```

[cabextract manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/man1/cabextract.1.html)

-l ; Lists the contents of the given cabinet files, rather than extracting them. I don't think you have to install **cabextract** if you have **lcab**.

```
 cabextract -l Swedish.cab

 File size | Date       Time     | Name
-----------+---------------------+-------------
    114323 | 12.03.2024 11:49:36 | affärskvinna.odt
     69425 | 12.03.2024 11:48:58 | aftonmåltid.pdf
    183907 | 15.03.2024 16:41:50 | folder/adjö.txt

All done, no errors.
```

Extract files from Microsoft cabinet (.cab) archives

```
cabextract Swedish.cab 

Extracting cabinet: Swedish.cab
extracting affärskvinna.odt
extracting aftonmåltid.pdf
extracting folder/adjö.txt

All done, no errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [PowerArchiver](https://www.powerarchiver.com/en-us/download-powerarchiver/) (and I think anything that uses `cabinet.dll` properly, rather than `makecab.exe`).

Example of usage with their command line tools:

```
pacomp -a output.cab C:\some\folder
```